# Print PDF file to printer on the network in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, printing

I'm working on an intranet using Laravel.

I generate a PDF and want to print this PDF automatically on a printer on the network.
Generating a PDF is not a problem, but I can't find a way to print it.
We are using a Power Server from IBM so the laravel-printing package won't work.

Someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to print it.

```
<script>
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Call the function with either a button click or sth else (For you call the function after generating the pdf)

Comment: We don't want the user to see anything about the printing. It is in the backend that the pdf is generated and needs to be printed to a printer